# Replace Pattern with ""

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I'm trying to write a regex that will take a string of the form:

```
<123>, ;<123>:::,<123>
```

where 123 is some number and in between the numbers is some punctuation.

I need a regex that will replace all the punctuation between the number fields with "".

I tried this:

```
Regex.Replace(s, ">.*<", "");
```

But had no luck. What regex would accomplish this?

Edit: My original regex was a bit misleading, sorry! As the commenters said, I'm looking for <123><123><123>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the exact C# syntax either, but if your string is guaranteed not to have numbers outside those angle brackets, then you should be able to get away with this:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "[^\d<>]*", "");
```

So remove anything that isn't a number or "<" or ">".  If you also want to remove the angle brackets it's even simpler:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "[^\d]*", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the `.*` part non-greedy, otherwise it will pick up everything between the first `>` and the *last* `<` in your string. Try something like:

```
Regex.Replace(s, ">.*?<", "");
```

This will erase the `>` and `<` chars also. If you want to preserve those:

```
Regex.Replace(s, ">.*?<", "><");
```

Comment: You don't need `@` - they are used to ignore escaped characters: `"\\d"` vs. `@"\d"`. This should do, but the output is `"<123123123>"`, which is weird, though it looks like what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Kobi sounds like the OP expects `"<123><123><123>"`

Comment: @Kobi: Thanks for the syntax tip!

Comment: @Mat, this also does the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both of these should work:

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"(\>|^).*?($|\<(?=\d{3}\>))", "$1$2");
```

or

```
String.Concat(Regex.Matches(s, @"\<\d{3}\>")
            .OfType<Match>().Select(a => a.Groups[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use brackets as suggested. but i didnt get what exactly you wanted to replace.

```
string s = "<123>, ;<123>:::,<123>";

s = (new Regex("[<>:, ;]")).Replace(s, "\"");
```

final string will be;

"123"""""123""""""123"